# Download xml.gz file with HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, ssl, https

I am trying to download an xml.gz file from a remote server with HttpsURLConnection in java, but I am getting an empty response.  Here is a sample of my code:

```
URL server = new URL("https://www.myurl.com/path/sample_file.xml.gz");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)server.openConnection();
connection.connect();
```

When I try to get an InputStream from the connection, it is empty. (If I try connection.getInputStream().read() I get -1)  The file I am expecting is approximately 50MB.

To test my sanity, I aslo tried entering the exact same url in my browser, and it did return the file I needed. Am I missing something?  Do I have to set some sort of parameter in the connection?  Any help/direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Is any exception being logged? Is the website presenting a self-signed SSL certificate, or one that is not signed by a CA? There are several reasons why it might work fine in your browser (the browser might have been told to accept self-signed certs from that domain) and not in your code.

What are the results of using [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) or [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to fetch the URL?

The fact that the InputStream is empty / result from the InputStream.read() == -1 implies that there is nothing in the stream to read, meaning that the stream was not able to even be set up properly.

**Update**: [See this page](http://www.howardism.org/Technical/Java/SelfSignedCerts.html) for some info on how you can deal with invalid/self-signed certificates in your connection code. Or, if the site is presenting a certificate but it is invalid, you can import it into the keystore of the server to tell Java to trust the certificate. [See this page for more info](http://www.chrissearle.org/blog/technical/adding_self_signed_https_certificates_java_keystore).

Comment: The third party that is supplying the file originally told me to use curl as follows:

curl --location -C - --digest -k
https://www.myurl.com/path/sample_file.xml.gz -o sample_file.xml.gz

this works fine too!

Comment: the -k switch with curl means "Allow connections to SSL sites without certs", so I think it's safe to assume that the site isn't presenting a valid certificate. You'll have to update your code to account for this

Comment: the curl command works without the -k switch.  I'm guessing that means that the cert is valid.

Answer (score 2):

1. Verify the `response code` is 200
2. Check that `connection.contentType` to verify the content type is recognized
3. You may need to add a Content-Handler for the GZ mime type, which I can't recall off the top of my head.

After the comment describing the response code as 3xx,

1. Set 'connection.setFollowRedirects(true)'

Should fix it.

Comment: The response code is 302, which means "the data requested actually resides under a different URL". I wonder if this is my problem... I guess this is why the provider told me to use the "-location" parameter when using curl to download the file. Is there any way around this?

Comment: 'connection.setFollowRedirects(true)' should do it.

Comment: The followRedirects property is set to true by default, and I was able to see the redirected url.  But, from your original answer, I noticed when I do connection.getContentType(), null is returned.  Does this mean I have to creat a ContentHandler[Factory] for mime type "application/x-gzip"?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the download wasn't working because the remote server was redirecting me to a new url to download the file.  Even though connection.setFollowRedirects(true) was set, I still had to manually set up a new connection for the redirected URL as follows:

```
if (connection.getResponseCode() == 302 && connection.getHeaderField("location") != null){
            URL server2 = new URL(connection.getHeaderField("location"));
            HttpURLConnection connection2 = (HttpURLConnection)server2.openConnection();
            connection2.connect();
            InputStream in = connection2.getInputStream();
}
```

After that, I was able to retrieve the file from the input stream.  Thanks for all your help guys!

Comment: I noticed this as well:

http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6810084